# SSDT: "Identifiers must include at least one name (for example, MyTable)"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, database-tools

Two days trying to find the origin of this error and can not ...

My problem is the same: [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/8788a92a-fc0e-4a5e-896d-285eeb639219/getting-error-during-database-publish-preview-identifiers-must-include-at-least-one-name-for?forum=ssdt)

When i build my db project the following error occur:

"Identifiers must include at least one name (for example, MyTable)"

Build output:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\Objetivo.Rango.BancoDados.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output "C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.SqlClrAttributes.cs"
>       Loading project references...
>       Loading project files...
>       Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies...
>       Validating the project model...
>       Writing model to D:\WorkspaceObjetivoSistemas\ObjetivoSistemas\Rango\RamoPrincipal\Rango\Objetivo.Rango.BancoDados\obj\Debug\Model.xml...
>       Writing create script to Rango_Create.sql...
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(546,5): Error:  : Identifiers must include at least one name (for example, MyTable).
>   Done building project "Objetivo.Rango.BancoDados.sqlproj" -- FAILED.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Finally solved my problem.

There was a bug in **`.refactorlog`** file...

This error message is too vague and it's not enough to know where the problem is happening ...

Comment: Deleting the refactor log fixed this for me

Comment: In my case, I could not delete it, since I had made several renames in my objects. If I deleted, I would need to reapply renames to a refactor generation or create them manually in the file later. But delete the .refactor file will solve the problem.

Comment: In my case I caused the error in the refactor log by doing a find replace in my entire solution when I was doing some refactoring. The manual edit in the refactorlog corrupted it along the way.

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally reproduced this by using the *Refactor* menu tool to rename some columns, making several other changes, then UNDOING all changes via TFS.

A couple of original refactor items were left in the *.refactorlog* file after the Undo. Once I removed them from the xml, publishing worked as expected.